# Xcode Target Membership Lost the Plot

Tags: xcode4.3, ios5.1, targeting

Xcode 4.3.3 project with 3 targets, each target has it's own InAppPurchaseManager class.  Suddenly out of the blue, target ABC has build errors because it's pointing to target XYZ's InAppPurchaseManager class.  The individual InAppPurchaseManager classes all belong only to there respective targets.  I discarded changes (reverted to last update in Cornerstone) and it still happens!  If I delete reference to InAppPurchaseManager for other targets, problem for ABC goes away.

I'm wondering if anyone else has experienced this and knows how to fix?
I'm guessing something has been corrupted but reverting back to previous version didn't fix so I doubt it's the project file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's fixed itself with Xcode 4.5.1